# Automapper does not ignore 2nd level nested property when asked to

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Having some trouble with the Automapper 'Ignore' option.  Here is a test outlining the issue I'm having:

```
    using AutoMapper;
    using NUnit.Framework;

    [TestFixture]
    public class Sample
    {
        public class OuterSource
        {
            public InnerSource Inner { get; set; }
        }

        public class InnerSource
        {
            public InnerInnerSource InnerInner { get; set; }
        }

        public class InnerInnerSource
        {
            public int Value { get; set; }
        }

        public class OuterDest
        {
            public InnerDest Inner { get; set; }
        }

        public class InnerDest
        {
            public InnerInnerDest InnerInner { get; set; }
        }

        public class InnerInnerDest
        {
            public int Value { get; set; }
        }

        [Test]
        public void MergeMap_WhenIgnoringLevel2InnerProperty_PropertyRemainsUnchanged()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<OuterSource, OuterDest>();
                //.ForMember(d => d.Inner, opts => opts.Ignore());  // test passes when added back in
            Mapper.CreateMap<InnerSource, InnerDest>()
                .ForMember(d => d.InnerInner, opts => opts.Ignore());

            var source = new OuterSource { Inner = new InnerSource { InnerInner = new InnerInnerSource { Value = 25 } } };

            var destination = new OuterDest { Inner = new InnerDest { InnerInner = new InnerInnerDest { Value = 99 } } };

            Mapper.Map(source, destination);

            Assert.That(99 == destination.Inner.InnerInner.Value);  // FAIL - destination.Inner.InnerInner is null
        }
    }
```

It appears that the 'ignore' option is not fully working.  If I comment back in the 1st 'ignore' then everything works as expected.  The issue is that there are a number of other properties on the Inner class that I need mapped.  The only one to ignore is the InnerInner class.

Any ideas?  The same issue, I think, was outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188952/automapper-doesnt-ignore-nested-types) but the accepted answer does not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggested way to use AutoMapper is to map types, just as mentioned in the referenced post. So you never create the destination object, just specify the type that you want to map to.

```
var dest = Mapper.Map<OuterSource, OuterDest>(source);
```

Is it possible for you to use it in this way and then have the value of dest.InnerInner set at a later point in time?

Comment: Literally 5 minutes ago, that is almost exactly what I ended up doing.  You can use Automapper to map to an existing object.  I just needed to ignore the entire 'Inner' property. Then, like you say, add an AfterMap on the OuterSource mapping to get at the properties I need to.

Answer (score 0):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<InnerSource, InnerDest>()
    .ForMember(d => d.InnerInner, opts => opts.UseDestinationValue());

Mapper.CreateMap<OuterSource, OuterDest>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Inner, opts => opts.UseDestinationValue())
    .AfterMap((source, destination) => Mapper.Map(source.Inner, destination.Inner));
```

Comment: This is what I do. I think it is almost @codemonkey said but exemplified.